# Find distinct values faster

Tags: postgresql, distinct

I have the following table (I've simplified it):

```
CREATE TABLE user_action_history (
    id serial,
    user_id integer,
    page_id integer,
    ts timestamp,
    ...
);
```

I run this query on it to find out which pages my user has accessed:

`SELECT distinct page_id FROM user_action_history WHERE user_id=$id`

I already have an index on (user_id, page_id) and it does an index only scan but that's  not fast enough, sometimes it takes 2-3 seconds on my 4.5M rows.

I suppose I could create another table with unique user_id, page_id values and a row counter column and maintain it with triggers but I was wondering if anyone has a more creative solution. I have postgres 9.5 which will not be upgraded anytime soon, so that's a limitation.

Edit: this is how an explain (analyze, buffers) of the query above looks like:

```
 HashAggregate  (cost=2010.74..2010.75 rows=1 width=2) (actual time=3483.189..3483.193 rows=26 loops=1)
   Group Key: page_id
   Buffers: shared hit=65 read=277
   ->  Index Only Scan using user_action_history_idx on user_action_history  (cost=0.43..1966.96 rows=17513 width=2) (actual time=29.588..3480.510 rows=15747 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (user_id = 10)
         Heap Fetches: 2142
         Buffers: shared hit=65 read=277
 Planning time: 53.465 ms
 Execution time: 3483.242 ms
```

Comment: Is the table vacuumed often enough?

Comment: Please show an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` of it being slow.

Comment: Here you go, I've edited the question. If nothing else, I've learned about the BUFFERS option, that's already something.

Comment: That looks like impressively bad, or maybe overloaded, hardware.  Vacuuming might help.  But what is this machine, and the storage?

Comment: "**sometimes** it takes 2-3 seconds on my 4.5M rows." - what means "sometimes" here? Does that means that sometimes it's  fast?

Comment: "Sometimes" mean when it hasn't been read for a while. On second read the "Buffers" lines only show shared hits and the execution time becomes 5 ms or so. Vacuuming shouldn't be a problem, all tables should be vacuumed regularly, but I'll do more tests to be sure. Probably the hardware is the problem, it's a vitrual machine so I don't know much about it but the main table is on some raid from rotational HDDs and the index is on an SSD.

Comment: So, it looks like it was indeed a vacuuming problem, after I did a manual vacuum, the Buffers from the plan changed to: `shared hit=17 read=86 dirtied=9` and the execution time to 30.253 ms. I've checked and the project's nightly vacuuming strategy was based only on dead tuples which this table hasn't got many, I'm rewriting it right now. I still don't understand though why reading 3.22 times as many pages takes 100 times longer.